# How to access the wampserver localhost of another computer

Tags: php, apache, wampserver, windows-server-2016

I have a wampserver 3.0.6 installed in windows server 2016 with a public ip xxx.xxx.xx.xx

I have make changes to httpd.conf file like below:

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    AllowOverride all
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and in httpd-vhosts.conf file as:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

Now When i try to access the localhost by entering "xxx.xxx.xx.xx" from other computer I am not getting the response.

This question is asked many times in stackoverflow. But those solutions given didnot worked so I am asking here this question again.

Can anybody figure out how to fix this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: I assume the other computer is in the same network?

Comment: Yes same network

Comment: I tried all possible solutions but none of them worked for me. So I solve the problem by disabling the firewall for port 80

Comment: `httpd-vhosts.conf` takes preference over `httpd.conf` so set `Require all granted` in `httpd-vhosts.conf`and leave `httpd.conf` as `Require local`

Comment: @RiggsFolly. I already tried changing the vhosts but it didnot worked so create a inbound for disabling port 80

Comment: _so create a inbound for disabling port 80_ Sorry I dont understand

Comment: disabling the firewall for port 80.

Go to Search on windows.
search "firewall".
open the "firewall with advanced".
go to inbound rules.
click on "new rule".
select the "Port" option.